# error in if-statement, requires scalar logical expression

Tags: if-statement, types, fortran

Within a subroutine I try to create a statement, however it will only work if I enter a number directly, as soon as I replace the number with a variable, it will give the error:

```
||Error: IF clause  requires a scalar LOGICAL expression|
```

In this example var is a real number between 0 and 1.

```
    if ( var%type3 < 0.5) then
            test = 1
    end if
```

where the `type3` component is declared as

```
    real, dimension(1,1) :: type3
```

Does someone maybe know what we are doing wrong. Because the error does not give us any clues which part of the statement is wrong.

Comment: If, as you state, `var` is a real number what is `var%type3` ?  In Fortran real numbers don't have components that you can access using the `%` notation.

Comment: after variable in every function i used the percentage sign with its type. This worked in other subroutines as well. type3 is defined as real, dimension(1,1). However is if i remove that part and only leave var < 0.5 it will give:                                                                     
                                                                                                                                                

    ||Error: Operands of comparison operator '<'  are TYPE(types)/REAL(4)|

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You try to use a DIMENSION(1, 1) type as a REAL.

You shoul add (1, 1) to access to yout REAL contained in the DIMENSION(1, 1)

Use :

```
  IF ( var%type3(1, 1) < 0.5 ) THEN
     print *, 'IT WORKS'
  END IF
```

Exemple to get this error :

```
MODULE vardef
  TYPE vartype
     REAL :: type3(1, 1)
  END TYPE vartype
END MODULE vardef

PROGRAM test
  USE vardef

  TYPE(vartype) var

  var%type3(1, 1) = 0

  IF ( var%type3 < 0.5 ) THEN
     print *, 'IT WORKS'
  END IF
  RETURN

END PROGRAM test
```

Answer (score 1):

From your comment `var%type3` is a `real, dimension(1,1)`.  This isn't scalar, and `var%type3 < 0.5` will be an array of the same shape.

As the error message states, the test condition for the `if` should be scalar logical.  Depending on what you want to do your test condition can be one of a non-exhaustive list:

- `var%type3(1,1) < 0.5`
- `ALL(var%type3 < 0.5)`
- `ANY(var%type3 < 0.5)`

The first case seems natural as it is a scalar condition, but I leave the others as you may well be expanding to cases where it isn't a (1,1) array.